# How to select parents based on all associated children passing certain criteria in Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a parent class that has many children. The children hold important time information in a date_time column. How do I select a parent record only if the children all pass the required criteria which I am defining as `min(children.start_time) > ? AND min(children.start_time) < ?, Time.now, Time.now.end_of_month + 2.month`

I have tried a number of solutions which have all given me back incorrect data. An example of what I have tried:

```
Parent.where(is_active: true).joins("LEFT JOIN children ON parents.id = children.parent_id").group("parents.id").group("children.start_time").having("min(children.start_time) > ? AND min(children.end_time) < ?", Time.now, Time.now.end_of_month + 2.month)
```

This query gives me back parents where the children has start dates before Time.now which is not what I am after.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

```
Parent.where(is_active: true).joins(:children).group("parents.id").having("min(children.start_time) > ? AND min(children.end_time) < ?", Time.now, Time.now.end_of_month + 2.month)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great time to use a `merge` method.

To start with - create a `scope` in your children class:

```
scope(:near_start, -> { where('min(start_time) > ? AND min(start_time) < ?, Time.zone.now, 2.months.from_now) })
```

(Should it really be `min` on both criterions?

```
Parent.joins(:children).merge(Child.near_start)
```

I do not have any good example to test on right now, so I am not 100% sure what you need to assure that it checks **all children**, I guess that it can be done with `group` and/or `having`.

I hope that it can guide you a bit.

Comment: Thanks. I've figured it out with `group` and `having`. It's more performant to run the query in the DB than manipulating with Ruby later. Also Postgres won't let you mix where and min ... it gives the following error `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE`

Comment: Nothing in my example would be processed in ruby, or what did you mean? I haven't used many aggregate functions in Postgres. Glad it could help

Comment: Merge is a method from the Ruby hash class.

FYI: I just Benchmarked it and the direct query in DB that I posted on my answer is almost 4 times quicker than merge method approach you suggested.